# firebase functions deployment error: Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

When I deploy storage trigger functions I get the following error msg and the deployment fails:

> Deployment error.
>   Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket Bucket-Name. Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again.

Firestore trigger functions can be deployed. I already tried to fix the ACLs using the commands suggested [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/107#issuecomment-295865335) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/issues/184#issuecomment-290914672).

Any ideas how to fix that?

Edit: I set up a new project, facing the same error. 
My /functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<project-name>.firebaseio.com"
});

const storage = admin.storage();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Im deployed successfully");
});

exports.storageTrigger = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onChange(event => console.log('I fail to deploy'));
```

Comment: Please contact Firebase support to help diagnose.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: facing the same issue today. Earlier it was working fine. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It appears that without changing anything on my end, it is fixed by now and deployment of storage trigger functions works again! Thanks Firebase Team!

Comment: Yes. I had raised a support request with the firebase team. Got the below reply 10-15 mins back.
`There was a known bug with Cloud Functions deployment and our engineers have resolved this internally. Apologies for the inconvenience this may have caused.

After getting the latest updates from them, the fix has now been officially released. You may try to re-deploy your functions again.`